# why framer motion exit animation not working when changing URL manually?

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-router, framer-motion

I have some routes and I used **AnimatePresence** component from **framer motion** to make animation for routes. here is my structure:

in index.js file:

```
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
   </BrowserRouter>
```

in App component file :

```
  <AnimatePresence mode="wait">
  <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
    <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
    <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
  </Routes>
</AnimatePresence>
```

the animation on entering and exiting works fine while I change URL with **navigate()** from **useNavigation** hook but when I input URL manually only entering animation works and animation on exit ( when I change URL manually) does not work. I guess it has something with rendering the whole document and backend thing but I don't know how to solve it. currently I am working on localhost

Comment: Manually changing the URL makes a page request to the server, i.e. the page is reloaded... the React app remounts. Any React state/etc that was running is immediately dumped when reloading the page.

Comment: should I use Nextjs ?

Comment: That won't change the default browser behavior when manually changing the URL. AFAIK there's nothing you can do to change this. I'd say it's the expected behavior.